# Hypergeometric distribution, $Hg(1,a,b)$ follows Bernoulli with $Be(\frac{a}{a+b})$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function, bernoulli-numbers

The probability function of Hypergeometric distribution , $Hg(n,a,b)$ is
$$P(X=m)=\frac{\binom{a}{m}\binom{b}{n-m}}{\binom{a+b}{n}}$$

I have to show $Hg(1,a,b)$ follows Bernoulli with $Be(\frac{a}{a+b})$

I noticed if i put $m=1$ when $n=1$ then i get the desired $Be(\frac{a}{a+b})$.

But i have not understood why will not i consider $m=0$ ?

Comment: "why will not i consider m=0 ?"... You are very much required to consider m=0 as well.

Comment: @Did If i consider $m=0$ then i get $\frac{b}{a+b}$. And if i sum the result for $m=0$ and $m=1$ then i get the result $1$.How should i complete the proof?

Comment: The proof seems complete to me...